# i want to get the sum of one or two column in one select query

Tags: sql

please help me to query
i want to sum one column in the table between entry date

example:

```
SELECT * FROM `transaction` WHERE entryDate BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-31'
```

Comment: provide some sample data and your expected output

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this for just a single column is to just take the sum:

```
SELECT SUM(some_col)
FROM `transaction`
WHERE entryDate BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-31';
```

If you wanted to take a number of sums, each with different criteria, then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN entryDate BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-31'
             THEN some_col END) AS some_col_sum,
    -- other conditional sums here
FROM `transaction`;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  ID, col1+ col2
FROM    TableName